# msbuild: how to select the application store for configuration

Tags: delphi, msbuild

I use this line to build the apk of my delphi (berlin) app:

> MSBuild myapp.dproj /p:Config=Release /p:Platform=Android /t:Build;Deploy

but i don't know how to set the **application store** or **development** configuration (what we do in project manager > target platform > Configuration

what the proper parameter to use ?

Answer (score 1):

The difference seems to be in the `Cfg_1` item:

```
msbuild /t:Build /p:Platform=Android /p:Cfg_1=true MyApp.dproj
```

seems to activate Application Store, and

```
msbuild /t:Build /p:Platform=Android /p:Cfg_1= MyApp.dproj
```

seems to activate Development.

Comment: hmm, how you find it that it Cfg_1 ? why not Cfg_2 ?

Comment: @Waslyva Check your .dproj file.

Comment: i checked, and i saw 2 option, one cfg_1 and one cfg2, and cfg_1 seam for debug: ie i have this: <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Cfg_1)'!=''">
        <DCC_Define>DEBUG;$(DCC_Define)</DCC_Define>
        <DCC_DebugDCUs>true</DCC_DebugDCUs>
        <DCC_GenerateStackFrames>true</DCC_GenerateStackFrames>
        <DCC_DebugInfoInExe>true</DCC_DebugInfoInExe>
        <DCC_RemoteDebug>true</DCC_RemoteDebug>
    </PropertyGroup>

Comment: but none of them say anything about application store :(

Comment: @Waslyva For me, `/p:Cfg_1=true` does. Try `/v:diagnostic`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to sign in to store first to deploy your application to it, You should be able to find deploy to store options for that